# Optimization of the log-absolute: reformulating to DCP-compliant on Julia

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, julia

I am trying to reformulate this optimization problem in order to get a DCP-complaint expression on `Julia` (I am using the `Conjex.jl` package)

$$
\text{Minimize}\;\;\; \mid\log(x)\mid
$$

The code

```
p = Variable()
f = abs(log(p))
```

Prompts to a warning

> WARNING: Expression not DCP compliant. Trying to solve non-DCP compliant problems can lead to unexpected behavior.

I am beginner regarding convex optimization. But, [as far as](http://cvxr.com/cvx/doc/dcp.html#functions) I read

> CVX-family does not consider a function to be convex or concave if it is so only over a portion of its domain, even if the argument is constrained to lie in one of these portions

Hence, the function $\mid x\mid$ is nonincreasing for $x < 0$, and nondecreasing for $x>0$. I suppose that the [composite property](http://cvxr.com/cvx/doc/dcp.html#compositions) fails because of it.

How to reformulate it in order to get DCP-compliant expresison?

PS: solutions using other scientific programming languages (Matlab, R, Python...) is welcome too.

Comment: `log(x)` is not convex anywhere (it is concave). So `|log(x)|` is also not convex.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen nice, so how to reformulate this expression?

Comment: Not all problems are convex or can be convexified. (After all, why would global solvers exist).

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen and can this problem be convexified?

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen yeah, that is my question, can I state that this problem is equivalent to?
$$
\text{Minimize}\;\;\; \mid x - 1 \mid
$$

Comment: Solve $|\log(x)| = 0$, or $\log(x)=0$. I.e. $x=1$

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen it is important to say that my real problem is not so trivial as 
$$
\text{Minimize}\;\;\; \mid\log(x)\mid
$$
I simplify it here just to discuss how to reformulate this part, which is nonconvex. Hence, solving the problem in the way you suggested is not possible

Comment: For large non-convex problems, we often use general-purpose nonlinear solvers (local solvers). We can use multi-start techniques to at least prevent really bad solutions. Only for smaller problems can we use global solvers that provide "proven" global solutions. Many problems are just not convex, so convex solvers cannot be used.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that the problem is nonconvex, but since the function is piecewise monotone, you could separately solve

$\min x$

subject to

$x\geq 1$

plus other constraints

and

$\max x$

subject to

$ x <= 1$

plus other constraints

and pick the better of the two solutions.

Comment: Or use binary to solve as a single MIDCP formulation.